# Spaceship operator on arrays

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

The following code is intended to implement comparison on an object that contains an array. Two objects should compare as `<,==,>` if all array elements compare like that. The following does not compile for a variety of reason:

```
#include <compare>
class witharray {
private:
  array<int,4> the_array;
public:
  witharray( array<int,4> v )
    : the_array(v) {};
  int size() { return the_array.size(); };
  auto operator<=>( const witharray& other ) const {
    array< std::strong_ordering,4 > cmps;
    for (int id=0; id<4; id++)
      cmps[id] = the_array[id]<=>other.the_array[id];
    return accumulate
      (cmps.begin(),cmps.end(),
       std::equal,
       [] (auto x,auto y) -> std::strong_ordering { return x and y; }
       );
  };
};
```

First of all, the array of comparisons:

`call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'array<std::strong_ordering, 4>`

Then the attempt to accumulate the comparisons:

`no matching function for call to 'accumulate'`

Compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/E3ovh5qGa

Or am I completely on the wrong track?

Comment: I don't even understand what you're trying to do. What meaning do you want this comparison to have?

Comment: Please provide [mcve] possibly using something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/Tr63PTfbY and clearly state what is your: compiler, problem and what are you trying to achive!

Comment: Or use [this as starting point](https://godbolt.org/z/E3ovh5qGa).

Comment: @Barry explanation added.

Comment: @MarekR thanks for  creating that. I've put the link in the question. Also: description of what I'm trying to do added at the top.

Comment: You just copied link. I could [edit] your question to do it for you. Please update `TEST_CASE` so it is clear what are you expecting what operators should do. Note that this `cmps` can't be initialized and IMO it should not be needed. Also note difference between `std::equal` and `std::equal_to` (please please check documentation abut those two).

Comment: @MarekR Your test case is correct. If someone can get that case to work, I can do the other cases myself. The problem is really how to get it to compile to begin with.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/4drddWa8G

Comment: What do you want the result to be if you compare `{ 1, 2 }` against `{ 2, 1 }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Two objects should compare as `<`,`==`,`>` if all array elements compare like that.

This is a fairly interesting order. One thing to note here is that it's a *partial* order. That is, given `{1, 2}` vs `{2, 1}`, those elements aren't *all* `<` or `==` or `>`. So you're left with unordered.

C++20's comparisons do have a way to represent that: you have to return a `std::partial_ordering`.

The way that we can achieve this ordering is that we first compare the first elements, and then we ensure that all the other elements compare the same. If any pair of elements doesn't compare the same, then we know we're unordered:

```cpp
auto operator<=>( const witharray& other ) const
    -> std::partial_ordering
{
    std::strong_ordering c = the_array[0] <=> other.the_array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
        if ((the_array[i] <=> other.the_array[i]) != c) {
            return std::partial_ordering::unordered;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

This has the benefit of not having to compare every pair of elements, since we might already know the answer by the time we get to the 2nd element (e.g. `{1, 2, x, x}` vs `{1, 3, x, x}` is already `unordered`, doesn't matter what the other elements are).

This seems like what you were trying to accomplish with your `accumulate`, except `accumulate` is the wrong algorithm here since we want to stop early.  You'd want `all_of` in this case:

```cpp
auto comparisons = views::iota(0, 4)
    | views::transform([&](int i){
        return the_array[i] <=> other.the_array[i];
    });
bool all_match = ranges::all_of(comparisons | drop(1), [&](std::strong_ordering c){
    return c == comparisons[0];
});
return all_match ? comparisons[0] : std::partial_ordering::unordered;
```

Which is admittedly awkward. In C++23, we can do the `comparisons` part more directly:

```cpp
auto comparisons = views::zip_transform(
    compare_three_way{}, the_array, other.the_array);
```

And then it would read better if you had a predicate like:

```cpp
bool all_match = ranges::all_of(comparisons | drop(1), equals(comparisons[0]));
```

or wrote your own algorithm for this specific use-case (which is a pretty easy algorithm to write):

```cpp
return all_same_value(comparisons)
    ? comparisons[0]
    : std::partial_ordering::unordered;
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I can adapt that to my purposes. Btw, in your answer you have `1,2,x,x` unordered wrt `1,3,x,x` but it could be `<=`.  Which I did not include in my OP. I was being too terse. Make it `2,2,x,x` and `1,3,x,x`?

Comment: If you say that `{1,2} <= {1,3}` then what you have isn't even a partial order. Because `{1,2}` is not less than `{1,3}` (since 1 is not less than 1), and it's not equal either (since 2 is not equal to 3). Yet despite being neither less than nor equal, you want it to be "less than or equal".

Comment: @VictorEijkhout In case you didn't see what Raymond said. `x <= y` means `(x < y) or (x == y)`. If you want `{1, 2} <= {1, 3}` you have to pick one of `<` or `==` for the result of that comparison. And like... you _can_ define such an ordering (`x == y` if they all match. Otherwise,  `x < y` if none are greater. Otherwise, `x > y` if none are less. Otherwise, unordered) but that's different from what you said. In that world `{1, 2, 1} < {1, 2, 2}` but `{1, 2, 1}` is unordered with `{1, 3, 0}`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `std::array` already has spaceship operator which apparently does what you need:

```cpp
class witharray {
private:
    array<int, 4> the_array;

public:
    witharray(array<int, 4> v)
        : the_array(v) {};
    int size() { return the_array.size(); };
    auto operator<=>(const witharray& other) const
    {
        return the_array <=> other.the_array;
    };
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4drddWa8G

Now to cover problems with your code:

- `array< std::strong_ordering, 4 > cmps;` can't be initialized since there is no default value for `std::strong_ordering`
- use of `std::accumluate` here is strange there is better algorithm for that: [std::lexicographical_compare_three_way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare_three_way) which was added to handle spaceship operator
- You have feed [std::equal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) to `std::accumluate` as binary operation when in fact this is algorithm to compare ranges (it accepts iterators). Most probably your plan here was to use [std::equal_to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to).

Comment: Thanks. But I'm really hoping to learn how to write my own spaceship operator. For instance, suppose I want to compare the arrays lexicographically: 1,2,3 < 1,2,4 but also 1,2,3 < 1,3,1. Should I make a new question?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout The `operator<=>` of `std::array` already does lexicographical comparison.

Comment: "which apparently does what you need" It doesn't sound like that's what OP is asking for?

Comment: @user17732522 Ok, then reverse lexicographic. Point is that I want to know how to write my own spaceship operator.